# How do I change only a certain part of the code?

Tags: python, string, replace

I do not have a code but may I know how to do something like that:

I want to print " is happy." The outputs should be 
John is happy. 
Mary is happy. 
Tom is happy.

only the  part changes here so how can I do so with this {} included?

Comment: `x='John'; print(f'{x} is happy')` (on python 3.x), or `x='John'; print('{} is happy'.format(x))` on python 2.6+

Comment: Oh didn't know there is that function on python 3.x thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Have some kind of list of oyur names. Then you can print using a for loop

```
names = ["john", "mary"]
for name in names:
    print("{} is happy".format(name))
```

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you very much!